# Does this code leak memory (Objective-C global variables)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks

Will these two functions leak memory if they get called many times? My knowledge of Objective-C is very rudimentary. They seem fine to me but I don't have a good feeling about that implementation? Should I remove that "retain"?
Is that a proper way to store objects globally?

```
NSString* g_code = nil;

NSString* GetCode()
{
  if (!g_code)
  {
     std::string code = HelperFuncs::getCode();
     g_code = [[NSString stringWithUTF8String:code.c_str()] retain]; 
  }
  return g_code;
}

NSDictionary* g_options = nil;

- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary*)userInfo
{
    g_options = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:userInfo];
}
```

Comment: Where does `gameCode` come from? Do you know that 'GetCode()' is a C method?

Comment: Sorry I wrote it wrongly. This is defined in an external C++ file it just returns a the value of a #define but there many other functions like that too. getCode() { return CODE };

Comment: 1) Run the Analyzer in Xcode. It may point out if there is an issue. 2) Use the Leaks tool of Instruments on your app to see if there are any memory leaks.

Answer (score 1):

I would apply here the [singleton pattern](http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/) and if it is possible: use ARC, this makes life much easier.

Comment: That's some inherited code I need to use/adapt for a specific case and I don't even have the time to learn Objective C first. I cannot completely re-write it at this time. I'll check your suggestions.

Comment: If I remove all "retains" from the code will ARC work for global variables? I mean these values should remain valid for the whole lifetime of the game.

Comment: "I don't even have the time to learn Objective C first." -- Then you are likely to have many hard-to-fix problems. At a minimum, you have to get over to ARC. Trying to work without ARC *and* without actually understanding ObjC memory management is disaster.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know much about Objective-C and working on a Non ARC Project, then its really hard to handle memory. One thing may help you, if you convert your project to ARC.
 Go to Xcode -> Edit -> Convert -> To Objective-C ARC... This way convert your project to ARC and let me know if this helps